# Does SQL Server 2012 Lazy Join

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, left-join, database

I am working on an application that allows users to dynamically choose what they see. The list of columns and tables those belong to is huge. I'm working on building a dynamic query but I don't want to have to store all the join logic if I don't have too.
An example is I have a query that has LEFT JOINS for 10 tables but I only select and filter by one table. Is SQL Server 2012 Smart enough to not join on the other tables that are not needed?

I know Oracle's DBMS works like this but my company uses SQL Server 2012 so I'm stuck with that.

Example Query where the last 4 LEFT JOINS don't need to be performed:

```
SELECT [IncidentIncidentNumberModValue].[IncidentNumber]
    ,IncidentNumberModifierNotValue.[Value] AS IncidentNumberNotValue
    ,[Incident].[IncidentDate]
    ,[Incident].[ResponseNumber]
    ,[Incident].[PatientCareReportNumber]
    ,[IncidentType].[Value] AS IncidentType
    ,[SceneStreetAddressModValue].[StreetAddress2] AS IncidentAddress
    ,IncidentStreetAddressNotValue.[Value] AS IncidentAddressNotValue
    ,COUNT(*) OVER() AS TotalRecordCount
FROM [EmsEvent].[Incident]
    LEFT JOIN [Resource].[IncidentType] ON [EmsEvent].[Incident].[IncidentType] = [Resource].[IncidentType].[IncidentTypeID]
    LEFT JOIN [EmsEvent].[IncidentIncidentNumberModValue] ON [EmsEvent].[Incident].[IncidentID] = [EmsEvent].[IncidentIncidentNumberModValue].[IncidentID]
    LEFT JOIN [GlobalResource].[IncidentNumberModifier] ON [EmsEvent].[IncidentIncidentNumberModValue].[NotValue] = [GlobalResource].[IncidentNumberModifier].[DataElementID]
    LEFT JOIN [GlobalResource].[NotValue] IncidentNumberModifierNotValue ON [GlobalResource].[IncidentNumberModifier].[NotValueID] = IncidentNumberModifierNotValue.[NotValueID]
    LEFT JOIN [EmsEvent].[Scene] ON [EmsEvent].[Scene].[IncidentID] = [EmsEvent].[Incident].[IncidentID]
    LEFT JOIN [EmsEvent].[SceneStreetAddressModValue] ON [EmsEvent].[Scene].[SceneID] = [EmsEvent].[SceneStreetAddressModValue].[SceneID]
    LEFT JOIN [GlobalResource].[IncidentStreetAddressModifier] ON [EmsEvent].[SceneStreetAddressModValue].[NotValue] = [GlobalResource].[IncidentStreetAddressModifier].[DataElementID]
    LEFT JOIN [GlobalResource].[NotValue] IncidentStreetAddressNotValue ON [GlobalResource].[IncidentStreetAddressModifier].[NotValueID] = IncidentStreetAddressNotValue.[NotValueID]
    LEFT JOIN [EmsEvent].[CustomConfig] on [EmsEvent].[Incident].[IncidentID] = [EmsEvent].[CustomConfig].[IncidentID]
    LEFT JOIN [EmsEvent].[IncidentDisasterType] on [EmsEvent].[Incident].[IncidentID] = [EmsEvent].[IncidentDisasterType].[IncidentID]
    LEFT JOIN [EmsEvent].[Response] on [EmsEvent].[Scene].[SceneID] = [EmsEvent].[Response].[SceneID]
    LEFT JOIN [EmsEvent].[CrewMember] on [EmsEvent].[Response].[ResponseID] = [EmsEvent].[CrewMember].[ResponseInformationID]

WHERE [EmsEvent].[Incident].[DeletedStatus] = 0
    AND [EmsEvent].[Incident].AgencyID = '607CEE05-276D-49A1-B6BF-FD606EFC2377'
ORDER BY [EmsEvent].[IncidentIncidentNumberModValue].[IncidentNumber] ASC
OFFSET 0 ROWS
FETCH NEXT 25 ROWS ONLY
OPTION(recompile)
```

Comment: Using `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` will tell optimizer to create new query plan every time the query is executed. If you have `JOINs` that are not needed, they will be excluded. Make sure there no filters on "unused" joined tables.

Comment: Hmm, when I add that to the end of my query the execution plan still shows that is joined unneeded tables. Is there a trick to getting this to work how I need it to work?

Comment: I updated the original post with the query in question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on what column in the left outer joined table you are using in the join.

If the column is a primary key or has a unique constraint the table will be excluded from the query plan if it is not referenced elsewhere in the query.

It does not look like your last four tables are joined on their respective primary key.

With tables like this:

```
create table Parent
(
  ParentID int primary key
)

create table Child
(
  ChildID int primary key,
  ParentID int references Parent(ParentID)
)
```

This query will not use the table `Parent`.

```
select C.*
from Child as C
  left outer join Parent as P
    on P.ParentID = C.ParentID
```

[image]

But this query have to use the left outer joined Child table because it might add rows to the result if there are more than one hit on the foreign key.

```
select P.*
from Parent as P
  left outer join Child as C
    on P.ParentID = C.ParentID
```

[image]

Comment: I see so because I'm joining on the foreign key on those tables SQL Will try to join them anyway.
Would adding a DISTINCT change that?

Comment: @Ranger1230 Yes, at least in the simple case I have in my answer. Then SQL Server will know that the join can not be responsible for adding more rows to the resultset.