# How do I have SQL JOIN done depending on some condition?

Tags: sql, sql-server, left-join

I have two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE Users(
    UserId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    UserName NVARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    -- some other columns
    CurrentSubscriptionId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NULL,
)

CREATE TABLE Subscriptions(
    SubscriptionId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    UserId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL,
    -- some other columns
)
```

and I have a stored procedure that retrieves a list of "users" with their "current subscriptions":

```
SELECT List-Of-Columns FROM Users LEFT OUTER JOIN Subscriptions ON
   Users.CurrentSubscriptionId=Subscriptions.SubscriptionId
WHERE SomeConditionOnUsers
```

The point is I only need data from "subscriptions" for some calls of the stored procedure, not the others. So I'd add a `@includeSubscriptionData` bit parameter to the stored procedure (this is pseudocode, I'd have to list each conditionally included column separately):

```
SELECT List-Of-Columns-FromUsers,
    CASE WHEN @includeSubscriptionData THEN Columns-From-Subscriptions ELSE NULL END
FROM Users LEFT OUTER JOIN Subscriptions ON
   Users.CurrentSubscriptionId=Subscriptions.SubscriptionId
WHERE SomeConditionOnUsers
```

to hopefully avoid the JOIN. So I tried this first:

```
DECLARE @includeSubscriptionData BIT;
SET @includeSubscriptionData=0;
SELECT List-Of-Columns-FromUsers,
    CASE WHEN @includeSubscriptionData THEN SubscriptionId ELSE NULL END
FROM Users LEFT OUTER JOIN Subscriptions ON
   Users.CurrentSubscriptionId=Subscriptions.SubscriptionId
WHERE SomeConditionOnUsers
```

and the plan shows that there're still accesses to "subscriptions".

How do I get rid of accesses to the second table when the bit is set to zero?

Comment: What's exactly the problem with SQL accessing the table `Subscriptions`?

Comment: My only thought to avoid touching the `subscriptions` table woul dbe to build your query via dynamic sql, but that has plenty of issues on its own.

Comment: @NickyvV The query runs longer and increases load on the server.

Comment: Might be of some interest http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20434556/does-sql-server-2012-lazy-join
So I would think CurrentSubscriptionID would need to at least be a FK

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried putting it in the join criteria?

```
DECLARE @includeSubscriptionData BIT;
SET @includeSubscriptionData=0;
SELECT List-Of-Columns-FromUsers,
    SubscriptionId
FROM Users LEFT OUTER JOIN Subscriptions ON
   Users.CurrentSubscriptionId=Subscriptions.SubscriptionId and @includeSubscriptionData = 1
WHERE SomeConditionOnUsers
OPTION(RECOMPILE)
```

Comment: Yes, I tried that - there's still access to the second table.

Comment: Add the recompile query hint. Editing to set that.

Comment: Yes, with the hint the access is conditional. I'm not sure the hint has no negative consequences.

Comment: Yes, the second table will appear in the query plan.  If you look at the "Actual Number of Rows" value in the plan, however, it will be zero i.e. no IO is performed.

Comment: In my tests, adding that query hint will actually get the second table to not appear in the query plan. YMMV

Answer (score 1):

### Method 1 - Control Flow

```
IF @includeSubscriptionData = 1
  BEGIN
    SELECT list
         , of
         , columns
    FROM   Users
     INNER
      JOIN Subscriptions
        ON Users.CurrentSubscriptionId = Subscriptions.SubscriptionId
    WHERE  SomeConditionOnUsers
    ;
  END
ELSE
  BEGIN
    SELECT list
         , of
         , columns
    FROM   Users
    ;
  END
;
```

### Method 2 - Modified Join

```
SELECT list
     , of
     , columns
FROM   Users
 LEFT
  JOIN Subscriptions
    ON Users.CurrentSubscriptionId = Subscriptions.SubscriptionId
   AND @includeSubscriptionData = 1
WHERE  SomeConditionOnUsers
```

Comment: This way I have to maintain the list of columns twice. And I tried the second approach - there's still access to the second table.

Comment: @sharptooth you can't have it both ways, my friend `;-)`

Comment: @sharptooth P.S. ultimately it sounds to me like the first is the best solution for you. If your only complaint is that you have to maintain two columns lists: that's not a valid reason. Lazy code = poor code `;-)`

Comment: @sharptooth probably worth a read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20434556/does-sql-server-2012-lazy-join?lq=1

Answer (score 0):

You can use IF/ELSE for this.

```
DECLARE @includeSubscriptionData BIT;
SET @includeSubscriptionData=0;

IF @includeSubscriptionData == 0
    BEGIN
        SELECT List-Of-Columns-FromUsers    
        FROM Users WHERE SomeConditionOnUsers
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
        SELECT List-Of-Columns-FromUsers    
        FROM Users LEFT OUTER JOIN Subscriptions ON Users.CurrentSubscriptionId=Subscriptions.SubscriptionId
        WHERE SomeConditionOnUsers
    END
```